# How can I collect statistical data and metrics for an entire TeamCity installation?

Tags: plugins, teamcity, metrics

We offer a TeamCity installation (with a number of build agents) as a shared resource to a number of distributed technology departments, across our mid-size company. Although we have a qualitative sense of how many departments and technologists are using our TeamCity installation, we'd like to start gathering some quantitative metrics around the use of this installation and the use of TeamCity in general.

Is it possible for us to gather installation-wide metrics and statistics (i.e. NOT PROJECT SPECIFIC)?

We're looking for metrics such as:

```
* # of projects in TeamCity
* # of builds processed hourly/daily
* # of build failures hourly/daily
* # of test-runs 
* Min/Avg/Max # of test failures per run
* Min/Avg/Max amount of time it takes to do each test-run
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your TeamCity data is in an external SQL server of some kind, you should be able to query that db directly to run these kinds of metrics.